# Calculation of elasticity for non-linear curve

Tags: r, numerical-methods

I've written this code to calculate the elasticity for econometric analysis. Basically, this algorithm estimate the function:

$$\epsilon(x) = \frac{x}{f(x)}\ f'(x)$$

```
###############################################


    elasticity<-function(y.p,x.p,band){                      
        require(KernSmooth)                          
        as.vector(y.p);as.vector(x.p)
            loess.fun<-locpoly(x.p,y.p,bandwidth=band)
                plot(loess.fun,type='l',lwd=2,lty=4,
                    ylim=c(0,100),xlab="Price",
                    ylab="Share", col=2,
                    main="Local Polynomials Estimation")
            loess.der<-locpoly(x.p,y.p,drv=1,bandwidth=band,
                          gridsize = length(y.p))
            y1<-as.vector(loess.der$y)
            eps<-matrix(NA,length(y.p),2)
            eps[,1]<-x.p
                for(i in 1:length(y.p)){
                    eps[i,2]<-x.p[i]/y.p[i]*y1[i]
                }
            j<-order(x.p)
            colnames(eps)<-c("Price","Elasticity")
        return(eps[j,])
    }

###############################################
```

Can I improve this algorithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll provide feedback from top to bottom:

```
1. elasticity<-function(y.p,x.p,band){
```

It's recommended to use spaces to make your code easier on the eyes. Spaces also avoid ambiguous situations for people who are not experts in R's syntax rules; for example, when someone sees `a<-b`, is it assigning `b` to `a`, or is it asking if `a` is less than `-b`? Maybe another way to convince you is to make you notice that R's compiled code does contain spaces (run `print(lapply)` for example); it shows that R's authors agreed that code readability was more important than compactness.

Now about the choice of arguments. Why not use the same argument names (and order) as `locpoly` since it is the main function being called here? So I'd recommend `x, y, bandwidth`. Or maybe `x.price, y.price, bandwidth` if it really helps knowing these are prices.

```
2. require(KernSmooth)
```

To convince you to use `library` instead of `require`, check http://www.r-bloggers.com/library-vs-require-in-r/.

```
3. as.vector(y.p);as.vector(x.p)
```

These two calls to `as.vector` do nothing if you do not assign the output. You probably meant to do:

```
y.p <- as.vector(y.p)
x.p <- as.vector(x.p)

11. y1<-as.vector(loess.der$y)
```

If you check using `is.vector()`, you will see that `loess.der$y` is already a vector, so `as.vector` is unnecessary.

```
12. eps<-matrix(NA,length(y.p),2)
```

Would a data.frame make more sense? Or if you really want a matrix, should use be using `cbind`?

```
14. for(i in 1:length(y.p)){
15.    eps[i,2]<-x.p[i]/y.p[i]*y1[i]
16. }
```

Here, you are really missing up on vectorization. This should be:

```
eps[, 2] <- x.p / y.p * y1
```

Overall, if defining a data.frame, appreciate the simplicity and readability of:

```
eps <- data.frame(Price = x.p,
                  Elasticity = x.p / y.p * loess.der$y)
```

Or if you want a matrix, just replace `data.frame()` with `cbind()`.

---

Taking all of my comments into account, your code could look like this:

```
elasticity <- function(x, y, bandwidth) {
   library(KernSmooth)      
   x <- as.vector(x)
   y <- as.vector(y)
   loess.fun <- locpoly(x = x, y = y, bandwidth = bandwidth)
   plot(loess.fun, type = 'l', lwd = 2, lty = 4,
        ylim = c(0, 100), xlab = "Price", ylab = "Share", col = 2,
        main = "Local Polynomials Estimation")
   loess.der <- locpoly(x = x, y = y, drv = 1, bandwidth = bandwidth,
                      gridsize = length(y))

   eps <- data.frame(Price = x,
                     Elasticity = x / y * loess.der$y)

   return(eps[order(eps$Price), ])
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, youre answer is complete and full of suggestions. But i've run the two algorithms and the results are the same,  so this means that it works :D

Comment: That's right, my suggestions were only to improve on your coding style, as there was nothing wrong in terms of *working* code.